# Changing Footer Text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a very noob question, but I have been knocking myself out and finally relented to visiting stackoverflow.

On my site - found at http://www.econotego.ca - there is footer text at the very bottom of the apge which details copyright information.

I can not for the life of me locate where to change the text to my relevant business name in the coding - if one of you could suggest where I look (file name), that would be amazing.

Thanks for your time!

Cheers,

SRM

Answer (score 1):

usually that's written in the file `footer.php`, which is inside the template folder of the template you are using. You should also be able to open it in Wordpress' backend (admin pages) via the "editor".

Answer (score 0):

if the theme is updated it will erase any changes you've made in the footer.php file, under "appearance/editor/footer.php. Consider making a child theme so can keep your changes. Maybe add a widget like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/) or similar.